# Inserir imagem javascript

Tags: javascript

Boas,
Pretendo inserir uma imagem de acordo com a quantidade de vezes existente na propriedade de um objecto. É mais facil de explicar com um exemplo:

Tenho este objecto:

```
var book = [
    {
        title: "O Tatuador de Auschwitz",
        stars: 4,
        Author: "Heather Morris",
        Validation: true
    }
]
```

e neste caso pretendo inserir uma imagem 4 vezes (de acordo com a propriedade Stars). Para tal criei um ciclo `for` da seguinte forma:

```
for (var s = 0; s < book.stars ; s++) {
            image(starj,s,100,20,20);
    }
```

`starj` esta definida com a imagem que pretendo inserir

o que estou a fazer de errado?

Obrigado

P.S. Ainda sou muito verdinho nisto..

Comment: Pode nos fornecer o exemplo de código completo que está utilizando?

Comment: Bem-vindo TiagoOliveira86, leia esse post para obter melhores respostas   https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Falta declarar o índice do Array e o campo que deseja obter `book[0]["stars"]`:

```js
var s;
var book = [
   {
       title: "O Tatuador de Auschwitz",
       stars: 4,
       Author: "Heather Morris",
       Validation: true
   }
];
for(s = 0; s < book[0]["stars"]; s++){
     var img = document.createElement("IMG");
     img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/F543MoZ.png";
     img.style.width = "30px";
     img.style.height = "30px";
     document.getElementById('imagens').appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="imagens"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado Gabriel, já descobri o que estava faltando. Sendo assim terminei o código desta forma:

```
for (var i = 0; i < book.length; i++){
fill(random(0,250), random(50, 175) , 219);
rect(10+i*120, 20, 90, 100);
fill(0, 0, 0);
text(book[i].title, 15+i*120, 29, 70, 100);
text(book[i].Author, 15+i*120, 82, 70, 100 );
    for (var s = 0; s < book[i].stars; s++) {
        image(starj,(i*120)+(s*15),160,30,30);
    }
```

Desta forma, a imagem das estrelas é inserida de forma horizontal com o numero de vezes presente da propriedade Stars do objecto Book.